# How to use Symantec Backup Exec with S3 Amazon Storage?

Tags: windows, backupexec, amazon-s3, symantec

Is there any proven efficient way on how to use Symantec Backup Exect for Windows Servers to use S3 as one of the Devices to backup to.  Even if it means to use a plug-in to make it work.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As of Backup Exec 16 Feature Pack 2, released in 2017, Backup Exec supports backup to "S3 compatible" storage.

There was support in Backup Exec 15 for backup to AWS through the AWS Storage Gateway Virtual Tape Drive.

Comment: Happy 10k day Evan!

Comment: Thanks, JS! Saturday was my birthday, so this is a bit like a late birthday gift. Now it's just me and splattne... heh heh...

Comment: I need to point out that, 11 years later, this answer is out of date.  Backup Exec has builtin support for Amazon S3.